# Android: setText onItemClick NPE

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, settext, onitemclick

I don't get why I am getting a NPE while setting a text view string. I use these all over but why a NPE on this onItemClick() method??

Thnx for your help.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        . . .
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.navigationTitle);
        String navTitle = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listLabel)).getText().toString();
        title.setText(navTitle);//<--NPE AT THIS LINE - NO OTHER INFO FROM LOGCAT THAT IS FROM MY CLASSES!!
        . . . 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

99% 'title' object is null, because it doesn't exist in the 'view' object which is passed in on onItemClick method.

Try changing view.findViewById to just findViewById, assuming the textview R.id.navigationTitle exists in the activity.

Comment: thnx +1 for getting me to think. [See my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11109111/742030)

Answer (score 1):

`TextView title` is null so try this if navigationTitle is in your main Activity Layout:

```
 TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.navigationTitle);
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        . . .
        String navTitle = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listLabel)).getText().toString();
        title.setText(navTitle);
        . . . 
}
```

Comment: thnx +1 for getting me to think. [See my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11109111/742030)

Answer (score 1):

Thnx for @imran khan & @azgolfer getting me thinking:

I changed:

```
TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.navigationTitle);
```

to:

```
TextView title = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.navigationTitle);
```

And now it's not null!!